# Реврайт главной страницы

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Как с главной страницы (index.php) сделать (index.php?engine=news)?

Вариант ли это сделать через .htaccess? Или как ещё можно сделать на PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так в самом начале списка:
`RewriteRule ^$ index.php?engine=news [L]`

**UPD:** Да, забыл про редирект. Без редиректа он просто отправит данные на этот адрес. Чтобы была переадресация, нужно так:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?engine=news [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @W_0rld , исправил

Answer (score -1):

Короче сделал на PHP:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/')
{
header("Location: $siteurl/news");
}
```

Comment: Ответ не соответствует вопросу. Совсем. (Пути в вопросе другие)